# /etc/default/locale permission denied help

Tags: 15.04, locale

When I try to change my locale I type

```
update-locale
```

and it says

```
/etc/default/locale can't write: permission denied
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
sudo update-locale
```

You need administrative permissions to run this command.